# PythonAirflow operator

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

We are currently using the Airflow Python operator to load parquet files from GCS storage to BigQuery. I want to be able to declare all the numeric columns in the source to Big Numeric, is that possible ?

```
bq_load = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id="gcs_to_bigquery_modified_airflow",
    bucket="{{ dag_run.conf['bucket'] }}",
    source_objects=["{{ dag_run.conf['name'] }}"],
    source_format ='parquet',
    destination_project_dataset_table="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_destination') }}", 
    create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
    write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
    autodetect=True
)
```

Comment: Do you have some code to share?

Answer (score 2):

You can manually define the schema using `schema_field` parameter of **GCSToBigQueryOperator**  instead of using `autodetect`.

Please see updated code below:

```py
bq_load = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id="gcs_to_bigquery_modified_airflow",
    bucket="{{ dag_run.conf['bucket'] }}",
    source_objects=["{{ dag_run.conf['name'] }}"],
    source_format ='parquet',
    destination_project_dataset_table="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_destination') }}", 
    create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
    write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
    schema_fields=[{"name": "sample_col_1", "type": "BIGNUMERIC", "mode": "NULLABLE"},{"name": "sample_col_2", "type": "BIGNUMERIC", "mode": "NULLABLE"}, {"name": "sample_col_3", "type": "BIGNUMERIC", "mode": "NULLABLE"}]
)
```

You may refer to this [GCSToBigQueryOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/6.1.0/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_bigquery/index.html#module-airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery) documentation for more details.

Comment: Yea, the issue is some of the tables fairly large with 500 plus columns.